# Two K-S tests on unrelated arrays produce identical test statistics and p-values in python

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am using the two-sample K-S test in python scipy.stats to  test for the null hypothesis that two samples were drawn from the same distribution. I have four arrays and am performing the test twice to compare the distributions of a1 vs. a2 and a3 vs. a4. Code below

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as stats
a1 = np.array([0.13409962, 0.19769357, 0.09881423, 0.16722408, 0.21558872, 0.16, 0.08888889, 0.13931889, 0.15797788])
a2 = np.array([0.3, 0.11818182, 0.21111111, 0.20175439, 0.14128728, 0.15679443, 0.30563515, 0.22826087, 0.13677812])
a3 = np.array([0.1532567 , 0.04942339, 0.07905138, 0.05016722, 0.0331675 , 0.02, 0.11111111, 0.13931889, 0.])
a4 = np.array([0.06666667, 0.04545455, 0.04444444, 0.02631579, 0.03139717, 0.06097561, 0.0191022 , 0.07608696, 0.03039514])

stats.ks_2samp(a1, a2)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.4444444444444444, pvalue=0.24999584817106832)
stats.ks_2samp(a3, a4)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.4444444444444444, pvalue=0.24999584817106832)
```

The test statistics and the p-values are the same. What does this mean about the data or the implementation in scipy?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Very interesting artifact of how the data was generated, IMO. In fact, one thing I checked was very telling; `stats.ks_2samp(a2, a4)` gives `Ks_2sampResult(statistic=1.0, pvalue=5.41e-05)`

Comment: Thanks for your response, G. Anderson. However I don't expect a2 and a4 to have anything to do with each other (as reflected in the result). Is there any particular meaning of 'statistic=1.0' other than that the ECDF's of the two distributions don't overlap?

Comment: I suppose I was unclear. For a dataset so small, it's interesting that the distributions would be so decisively different. k-s testing works better for larger datasets, and although it's odd that the pairwise test between the two sets of arrays comes out exactly the same, I would be hesitant to say anything about the underlying distributions without knowing more about how the data were drawn. For a further test, I bootstrapped the given samples to increase the sample size to n=1000, and the test statistics diverged somewhat